# Rails: inject JSON data into tableless PORO model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

Through Rails 5.2.1 initializer, I am importing `customers.json` to a tableless model without any use of DB features. This JSON data needs to be loaded in memory once on Rails startup and then accessed as needed throughout the whole app. On app restart, it is reloaded again.

What I did so far:

`initializers/json_loader.rb`

```rb
data = JSON.parse(File.read('tmp/customers.json'), symbolize_names: true)
JSONDatastore.new(data) # load into model
```

`app/models/json_datastore.rb`

```rb
class JSONDatastore

  def initialize(records)
    @records = records
  end

  def self.records
    return @records
  end
end
```

The problem: when I do it this way, in controllers I cannot get hold of the filled JSONDatastore instance which was set in the initializer. It is filled with JSON data in the initializer but when I try and access it somewhere in other controller by calling `JSONDatastore.records`, I get `nil` even though I set `config.cache_classes = true`

Is there a way for me to fetch that instance of `JSONDatastore` filled in initializer and access it in my controllers? I tried making my model a singleton and could get the instance through `JSONDatastore.instance`, but `@records` was `nil` again.

Comment: `new` should be defined on class instance. Yours is instance method that never gets called.

Comment: sorry @AlekseiMatiushkin, it was supposed to be `initialize`, not `new` - I just mistyped. Could you take a look again?

Comment: There are two different `@records`: the one assigned in `initialize` is  the _instance variable_, the one you read from is _the class instance variable_.

Comment: Thanks @AlekseiMatiushkin, removed class ivar definition. Still getting nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clearly understand the difference between class scope and instance scope. Your `records` is a class method returning *class instance variable*. What you set in `initialize` is the *instance variable*. They share the same name, but have nothing in common.

Set your *class instance variable* instead.

```
class JSONDatastore
  def self.assign(records)
    @records = records
  end

  def self.records
    @records
  end
end
```

And call `JSONDatastore.assign` instead of `new`.

---

If you are still after abusing the initializer to set the class instance variable, this would do:

```
def initialize(records)
  self.class.instance_variable_set(:@records, records)
end
```

Comment: Thank you, it works :) First I was trying to set an instance variable with new but then could not fetch that instance later in controllers as I did not have any handle pointing to that original instance. That did not work.

Thank you for that edit showing initializer with class instance variable. I used your first suggestion but it is interesting to see how the latter would work.